# Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line ?

Tags: line-breaking, text-decorations, soul

Sometimes I want to underline some text, and it extends past the end of a line.  Why does `\underline{}` not automatically wrap my text for me ?

Also, how can I underline text so that it will still wrap ?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

In text mode, the `\underline` command will enclose its argument in a horizontal box, which doesn't allow linebreaks. Use the `\ul` command of the [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul) package instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

A sentence that is just included to fill the line. \underline{Some text with underlining.}

A sentence that is just included to fill the line. \ul{Some text with underlining.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: As for *why* `\underline` works the way it does, see [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underline) entry in the TeX FAQ for starters. It would seem that Leslie Lamport (the author of LaTeX) implemented just a "quick fix", and that only later package authors came up with more satisfactory solutions for underlining. See sections 2 and 7 of the `soul` documentation to get an idea of how complicated things are.

Comment: This mostly answers my question, but do you also know why `\underline` has this behavior ?

Comment: There is also the `ulem` package with gives `\uline`. The package should be loaded with the `normalem` option, otherwise the `\emph` macro is changed to underline the text.

Comment: @gabkdlly: Basically `\underline` boxes the text using `\hbox`, i.e. the primitive version of `\mbox`. Both aren't breakable by design. The `ulem` package for example avoids this issue by boxing each word separately by searching for the spaces between them. This still doesn't allow for hyphenation.

Comment: The `soul` package gave me trouble when the underlined text contained `cite`. The `ulem` package worked better.

Comment: If there is a better way to do this that is non-breaking, it should be replaced in the main environment. I am restricted on the packages I can use, therefore I cannot fix this behavior because the improvements were never backported.

Comment: @VebjornLjosa It seems `soul` fails with inclusion of user-defined macro's as well.

Answer (score 60):

The `\ul` command from the `soul` package has troubles with Umlauts -- the `\uline` command from the `ulem` package doesn't and therefore seems to be the better option for those not exclusively writing in English.

Comment: One should, however, be aware that `ulem` doesn't support automatic hyphenation, so one has to manually hyphenate using `\-` with it.

Comment: Note: One issue I faced is with macros, which don't work with multi-line.  I tried with many packages, but none of them worked.  I recommend that you include the `\uline` OR `\ul`, etc. in your macro to get the intended effect of underlining.

Comment: `\ul{\mbox{Ü}}` or `\ul{\"U}` works but they're certainly not very convenient.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using the LuaTeX engine (or can use it) you could use the `lua-ul` package, that allows underlining without any restrictions on the input (unlike `soul`) and with fully functioning kerning, hyphenation, etc. (unlike `ulem`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm} % to show automatic hyphenation works
  \underLine
    {%
      This is some text that gets automatically hyphenated
      while being under%
    }lined.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, hyphenation even works correctly for words not completely inside the argument of `\underLine`.

Comment: Do somebody know, why the hyphenation works with `\underLine`, but doesn't with `\underline` (lower 'l' in command name)? Is `\underline` a different command which is not from suggested `lua-ul`? I'm just curious what's going on.

Comment: @MichalVician yes, `\underline` is not part of `lua-ul`. In LaTeX `\underline` uses the `\underline`-primitive in maths mode, and in text mode it's just a thin wrapper around the primitive using a `\hbox` and as such isn't line breakable.