# Text fails to wrap inside cells of tabular (even tabularx) possibly due to \multicolumn

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

```
\noindent\hspace{3ex}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X l}
    \underline{Computational Study on the Vibrational Thermodynamics of Solid Solutions} & 07/2017 - Present\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{- Random solid solution models were developed with \emph{special quasi-random structures} and modelled using \emph{density functional theory.}}
\end{tabularx}
```

I tried various suggestions from the web but can't seem to figure out how to wrap the text in the 2nd row which is basically a single merged column. Help is appreciated.

Comment: you are using `l` column which is always single line

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{...}` might help.

Comment: also why `\noindent\hspace{3ex}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X l}` ??? that will necessarily be 3ex too wide and be an over-full

Comment: Please also keepp in mind, that the `\underline` command does not allow for linebreaks. Depending on your text width, margins and the font size, you might end up with the text in the first column overlapping with the second column. Related: [Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9550/134144)