# Inline underlined spaces are getting out of margins

Tags: margins, underline

When trying to use underlined blank spaces for a questionary inside a book, I'm getting the underline out of document margings. Does anyone knows how to make underline command respect the document margins?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{elegantbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
% Underlined spaces command
\newcommand{\uline}[1]{\underline{\hspace{#1}}}

\title{Document Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Introduction}

\Large

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Test text test text test text test text. Test text test text test text test text test text. Test text test text test text test text. Test text test text test text test text test text.
  \item Test text \uline{4cm} test \uline{4cm} test text test text test text test text.
  % The following line is the one that is not respecting margins
  \item Test \uline{4cm} test text test text test text test text \uline{5cm} test text test text test text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/why-does-underlined-text-not-get-wrapped-once-it-hits-the-end-of-a-line)

Comment: choose: `\uline{2cm}` or  `\linebreak\uline{5cm}`

Comment: It is not  good idea break short places for answers, but if you want this,  forget about using `\hspace` or any other type of box. Think that latex boxes are like characters, unbreakables.  But  some like `\ul{~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~}` is easy to write, highly breakable ... and even look more like the final output.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, no, that was not answering my question. but thanks.

Comment: @Fran, I really appreciate the comments, those really helped me. I went with the `\ul{~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~}` option, easy to write and text doesn't get too hurt with the `\linebreak`