# \uline cannot wrap the line after texlive2021

Tags: wrap, underline, ulem

I need to underline some text and hope the text automatically wrap at then end of the line.

see [Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/why-does-underlined-text-not-get-wrapped-once-it-hits-the-end-of-a-line)

The `\uline` works with texlive2020

However, after upgraduated to **texlive2021**, it doesn't work anymore.

---

Update:

I found that it's about Chinese characters。

A simple example (`xelatex test.tex test.pdf`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fontset=windows]{article}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem}
\RequirePackage{ctex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    fffffffffffffff  & \parbox[t]{14em}{\uline {中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中 文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文中文}} \\
    fffffffffffffff  & \parbox[t]{14em}{\uline {english englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish englishenglish english}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

in texlive 2020, it's:

[image]

However in texlive 2021, it's:

[image]

Comment: You are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can just copy and test as is. We don't know what class or relevant packages you are using.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but `\centering` could never have done anything in that position I think.

Comment: For example where does `\uline` come from?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining what exactly it was you wanted to achieve with this code? It is not obvious what the end goal is.

Comment: If using LuaTeX is an option, ditch `soul` and/or `ulem` and use the `lua-ul` package, which is way superior.

Comment: @AndréC I know, but a casual person coming by does not.

Comment: @CSGrandeur Please give a minimum example that reproduces your problem as shown here [How to make a “minimum example”](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: With TeX Live 2020 I get the same output as with 2021; with TeX Live 2019 or earlier I get scores of errors