# How to use soul's `\ul` instead of `\underline` in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, soul, underline

I'm using TeXstudio on Linux, and there is an option under the LaTeX/Font Styles menu to underline the selected text. For convenience, I set <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> as a shortcut so that I can quickly underline things.

[image: The LaTeX/Font Styles menu with the "Underline - \underline" option highlighted. The shortcut Alt + U has been configured for this menu item.]

I decided to change to `soul`'s `\ul` instead of `\underline` in one of my documents because I don't want the underlined text to run into the margin (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/)). When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, I want TeXstudio to insert `\ul{}` (enclosing any selected text with the brackets) instead of `\underline`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a macro. In the `Macros` menu, click `Edit Macros...`, then `+Add`. Enter the info like below (you can name it whatever you like):
[image]

The `%|` means "put the cursor here".

If this does not overwrite the shortcut `Alt+U`, you may have to remove the default shortcut in `Configure TeXstudio->Shortcuts->LaTeX->Font Styles->Underline`.

Comment: Works beautifully—thank you! Out of curiosity, do you know what the **Abbreviation** field does? And FYI, the Alt + U was a custom shortcut that I set up (it's not a default as of right now).

Comment: It's a shortcut for the completer. You can read more about it here: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33