# Problem when using polyglossia and soul packages together

Tags: polyglossia, soul

The following code presents a strange error found using `polyglossia` and `soul` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=brazilian]{portuguese}
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\textit{bbb \& \ul{aaaaa}}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! Extra \else.
\portuguese@sh@tmp ...\portuguese@sh@next --\else
                                                  \expandafter \portuguese@@...
l.7 \textit{bbb \& \ul{aaaaa}}
```

Note that removing one "a" from `\ul{aaaaa}` does compile without error.

Is it a bug? From `polyglossia` or `soul`?

Comment: they are incompatible. soul is fragile anyway and the portuguese language uses with xelatex special code to split hyphens and this breaks. (It breaks for 5 char as the language sets hyphenmin to (2,3) and so with 5 chars hyphenation is tried. Use lualatex and the lua-ul package.

Comment: I changed by the `ulem` package, using the `\uline` command. ("The package should be loaded with the `normalem` option, otherwise the `\emph` macro is changed to underline the text.") https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/why-does-underlined-text-not-get-wrapped-once-it-hits-the-end-of-a-line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The incompatibility will be fixed in `polyglossia` v. 1.64.

Workaround until then is to disable `splithyphens` around the soul macros, as in:

```tex
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[variant=brazilian]{portuguese}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \begin{document}
    \textit{bbb \& \textportuguese[splithyphens=false]{\ul{aaaaa}}}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I get the following error using vanilla TeXlive installation: ```! Package xkeyval Error: `spithyphens' undefined in families `portuguese'.```

Comment: @LEo There is a typo on his code. It is supposed to be `splithyphens` and not `spithyphens`,

Comment: Yes, indeed. Fixed the code.